# Does Eclipse based graphical Camel editor from JBoss - RedHat codeready work only for camel in xml?

Tags: jboss, apache-camel

I have been looking for a visualizer for apache camel and found Eclipse based graphical Camel editor from JBoss. But after installation of RedHat codeready studio and using the sample project in it, seems like it supports only camel-context.xml. My routes are in Java DSL. Is there no tool available for visualizing Java routes

Answer (score 0):

No there is no visual tools for editing Java DSL.

Usually a real programming language such as Java is best used by developers whom can write code.

And for visual tools with drag/drop etc then its high level where such tool generates the "code" in a markup language such as XML, YAML or custom format.

The Java DSL is high level and non savy Java developers can get comforable with just coding. Also users that have started with the visual XML editor would after some time get used to working directly with the XML code.

Comment: I was looking for the visual tool not necessarily to generate code but to get a big picture of my project's routes which i could see all in one screen and stick it as poster just for reference, which will help in viewing the entire flow in a single page instead of navigating through the code which is not super easy with Java DSL. Just like a schema diagram for database tables/class diagram for a java project. Alas there are none!

Comment: The VSCode plugins for Apache Camel can show a tree graph of your Camel routes also if it's from Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hawtio with the Camel plugin [to visualize your Java DSL routes graphically](https://hawtio.github.io/hawtio/plugins/camel/). It also exposes a UI for viewing/downloading (and even editing) Java routes as XML, enabling you to bring them into the Eclipse-based FUSE Tooling, if you wanted to.

According to the Hawtio website, JBoss FUSE already includes Hawtio.